# which QtQuick version number should I use

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Lets assume that

- QtQuick adds in 2.7 compared to 2.4

  - some new functionality (new APIs)
  - some performance optimizations in existing functionality
- I don't need the new APIs added in 2.7 but I would like to have the performance optimizations

Should I use

> import QtQuick 2.7

or can I use

> import QtQuick 2.4

and still get the performance optimizations?

The reason I'm asking is that we still have to support some STB (Settop boxes) running older versions of Qt so I want to, preferably, keep support for them *and* benefit from performance optimizations on other platforms (PC, mobile, ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you do not need to change the minor import version in order to gain performance improvements. In 99% of the cases, the underlying implementation is the same for both import versions. It's only the new API that has been revisioned so that it's not visible unless you import the latest version, to avoid any potential conflicts with user code.

In theory, the framework could ship different type implementations for different minor versions, but this is rare. Adding a whole new versioned type would quickly bloat the library and things would get out of control.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was hoping for!